# Simple lambda expressions in python but occurs error 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison'

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

This is my code.

```py
def div_by_primes_under(n):
    checker = lambda x: False
    i = 2
    while i <= n:
        if not checker(i):
            # checker = (lambda f, i: lambda x: x % i == 0 or f(x))(checker, i) 
            checker = lambda x: (x % i == 0 or checker(x))
        i = i + 1
    return checker

print(div_by_primes_under(10)(12))
print(div_by_primes_under(10)(121))
```

And the error information seems to be

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hw2.py", line 106, in <module>
    print(div_by_primes_under(10)(12))
  File "hw2.py", line 102, in <lambda>
    checker = lambda x: (x % i == 0 or checker(x))
  File "hw2.py", line 102, in <lambda>
    checker = lambda x: (x % i == 0 or checker(x))
  File "hw2.py", line 102, in <lambda>
    checker = lambda x: (x % i == 0 or checker(x))
  [Previous line repeated 996 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

I modified it with the a nested lambda expression, which seems to have the same function as the former(the line that was annotated). The error message disappear and it runs as expected.

I wonder if this is related to the principles of Python interpreters.

Answer (score 0):

We can clarify this question with no lambda version.

```
def div_by_primes_under_no_lambda(n):
    def checker(x):
        return False
    i = 2
    while i <= n:
        if not checker(i):
            print(i, "outer")
            def outer(): 
                def inner(x):
                    return checker(x) or (x % i == 0)
                return inner
            checker = outer()
        i = i + 1
    return checker

print(div_by_primes_under_no_lambda(10)(12))
print(div_by_primes_under_no_lambda(10)(121))
```

It seems to be right. But we must notice that the environment of outer doesn't exist for **i and checker**. When we call **div_by_primes_under_no_lambda**, it  return a **checker** function which is a self recursion function.

Comment: This code leads to `NameError: name 'f' is not defined`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between `checker = (lambda f, i: lambda x: x % i == 0 or f(x))(checker, i)` and `checker = lambda x: (x % i == 0 or checker(x))` is the late binding of the variable `i`.

In the current lambda expression, `i` is bound by passing`(checker, i)`, but in the former expression, `i` is a variable defined outside the lambda function, since the lambda function is executed outside the loop, it captures the final value of `i` at the end of the loop. So it cannot capture different `i` values in each iteration.

Comment: Yeah, you are right.